# Set scroll area for UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a custom view controller and a UITableViewController as the view controllers on a UIPageViewController which scrolls vertically (swipe up to go down to the table view, and vice versa).

The custom view controller has a graph in the center of it ([JBChartView](https://github.com/Jawbone/JBChartView)) which has a function where you can drag along the graph to see the values of the plotted points.

Unfortunately, this collides with the vertical scrolling back and forth between the controllers. What I would like is a way to set the "scroll section" frame – basically the user can scroll down to the second view controller from the bottom half of the screen, that way both the graph and the scrolling work without conflict. Is there any way to set this?

Comment: Not posting this as an answer, because I don't have time to format it properly. Initialize your page view controller with only top view (with graph) in its data source, add a transparent button on its bottom half, bind the touchDown: event and add the bottom controller to the data source on this event to enable scrolling, remove it from the data source on viewDidAppear: of the first controller to make this "work" again